# How to fix "my interminable login" in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have some problem with my login code. After clicking the login the progress bar loads so long but nothing really happened.

I can not find what is wrong
I'm using php, mysql, volley library

This is my login code:
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText email, password;
private Button btn_login;
private ProgressBar loading;
private static String URL_LOGIN ="http://188.173.127.17/Login.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String mPass = password.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()) {
                Login(mEmail, mPass);
            }else {
                email.setError("Please insert email");
                password.setError("Please insert password");
            }
        }
    });

    final Button bSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignup);

    bSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

private void Login(final String email, final String password) {

```
loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                    if (success.equals("1")) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String username = object.getString("username").trim();
                            String email = object.getString("email").trim();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                                    "Success Login. \nYour Username : "
                                            +username+"\nYour Email : "
                                            +email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error" +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error" +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
{
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);
        return params;
    }
};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

}

Comment: you hide loading only `if (success.equals("1")) {`. You have to debug your code

Answer (score 0):

according to your code `onResponse()` AND `onErrorResponse()` mehtod not call;

this is come from some reason 
1- check your internet connection
2-check your url
3-you may forget to add permission internet
4-if you are on local you may forget run xampp
5-you may set Retry policy and set timeout to your connection thus add it according to following code :

```
loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                if (success.equals("1")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String username = object.getString("username").trim();
                        String email = object.getString("email").trim();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                                "Success Login. \nYour Username : "
                                        +username+"\nYour Email : "
                                        +email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error" +e.toString(), 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error" +error.toString(), 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      })
     {
     @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("email", email);
    params.put("password", password);
    return params;
        }
        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new 
          DefaultRetryPolicy(YOUR_TIMOUT_IN_MILLI_SECOND,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
      RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
      requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

AND important reason :
6- probably `onResponse()` is called and `success` is not equal to `1`
thus you must put `loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);` out of `if (success.equals("1")) {...}` condition